# Oracle decode statement

Tags: sql, decode

I have a query that returns null for ln_prd_typ. I want to replace nulls with NA how do I do that. 
Below is my query

```
select '211' as "Asset_id",
(Select decode( lv12.ATTRIBUTE4, '', 'NA', lv12.ATTRIBUTE4 )
                    FROM XXFMSLS. XXFM_FAH_CUSTOM_LVL2_RULES lv12
                    WHERE lv12.LEVEL2_RULE_KEY = lvl1.LEVEL2_RULE_KEY  ) as "LN_PRD_TYP"
from xxfmsls.XXFM_FAH_CUSTOM_LVL1_RULES lvl1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in the subquery, use `coalesce`:

```
select '211' as "Asset_id",
       (Select coalesce( lv12.ATTRIBUTE4, 'NA')
        FROM XXFMSLS. XXFM_FAH_CUSTOM_LVL2_RULES lv12
        WHERE lv12.LEVEL2_RULE_KEY = lvl1.LEVEL2_RULE_KEY
       ) as "LN_PRD_TYP"
from xxfmsls.XXFM_FAH_CUSTOM_LVL1_RULES lvl1;
```

If the problem is that you are still getting `NULL` values, it is because the subquery is not matching -- so the logic in the inner `select` never gets executed.  I would suggest a `left join` instead:

```
select '211' as "Asset_id",
       coalesce(lv12.ATTRIBUTE4, 'NA') as "LN_PRD_TYP"
from xxfmsls.XXFM_FAH_CUSTOM_LVL1_RULES lvl1 left join
     XXFMSLS.XXFM_FAH_CUSTOM_LVL2_RULES lv12
     on lv12.LEVEL2_RULE_KEY = lvl1.LEVEL2_RULE_KEY;
```

Comment: But outer join doesn't work with correlated subquery

Comment: I want level1 table outside the sub query

Comment: Select '211' as "Asset_id", 'LN' as AST_TYP, lvl1.ATTRIBUTE14 as "Bus_line", (select coalesce(lvl2.ATTRIBUTE4, 'NA') from XXFMSLS.XXFM_FAH_CUSTOM_LVL2_RULES lvl2 where lvl1.LEVEL2_RULE_KEY = lvl2.LEVEL2_RULE_KEY)as "LN_PRD_TYP" from xxfmsls.XXFM_FAH_CUSTOM_LVL1_RULES lvl1

Comment: The above query doesn't work it only works when level 1 table is inside dub query

Comment: @user803860 . . . I am unclear what your comments are referring to.  This answer is in response to the query in your original question.